# Opening a db/migrate/* file more effectively? Wildcard to complete the beginning of the name of the file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

Working from a bash shell and utilizing vim, I generally have a pretty effective workflow.  However, when I attempt to access files in the `db/migrate` directory of a rails project, it becomes very tedious to access the files as the each contain a long integer at the being of their file names.  I've tried `vim db/migrate/*name_of_migration.rb` but to no avail.

Is there a way to access files via wildcard of in this manor?

Comment: If you use git or mercurial then checkout [git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number) and/or [scm_breeze](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze) that may help you quickly get the name of modified files in the repo from the command line using numbers instead of their full names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using vim-7.3, then you can do this from inside vim:

```
:set path=/path/to/your/project/root/**
:find migrate/*cr<tab>
```

and vim will show you the possible candidates for completion.

Comment: This is very helpful but is there an equivalent for bash?  Something I may add to my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to achieve this functionality? I generally do not open files from the vim editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're typing the name of the migration correctly, I assure you that the `*` will match the leading digits.

For example, from the root of your project,

```
$ vim db/migrate/*create_users.rb
```

*will* open `20111123142812_create_users.rb`.

Otherwise, my preferred method is to use

```
$ vim db/migrate
```

to "open" the directory in vim, and use the in-vim navigator to select the migration you're interested in from the list of files.

Comment: How would one enable tab complete for a statement such as `vim db/migrate/*crea`?